# Is it possible to connect 2 separate VPNs?

Tags: vpn

I have to connect to a VPN that uses PPTP, and unfortunately PPTP doesn't work so well on many mobile networks, so I'm trying to come up with a solution to this. I only ever use the VPN for SSH access

I'm trying to come with a solution to this, I'm thinking I could have my own VPN in amazon AWS that uses L2TP, and then from there that server connect by PPTP.

So it would be like:

phone > L2TP > AWS > PPTP > VPN

Is it possible to connect two VPNs like that? Or can anyone suggest a better solution?

At the moment I'm using teamviewer on my phone, to connect to a laptop at home, to connect to the VPN, which is quite a messy task.

This will just be used by me, as mentioned below it is a kludgy solution, but it is only mainly for two weeks while I'm away from home so it'll do until I can get the sysadmin to consider allowing different protocols for the VPN.

Comment: Will this be used by multiple people eventually, or will you be the only one to use it?  I ask because a kludgy answer might work for one person.

Comment: Most (decent) routers have the option to allow multiple authentication methods i,e, L2TP, L2TP & PPTP, L2TP & Certificate etc. I suggest you look at the router configuration and see if you can configure the authentication method

Comment: It's not clear to me why you need the VPN from your phone to the AWS.  If your using SSH, it's relatively secure to connect from phone to AWS. Then run ssh through VPN tunnel to from AWS to server.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible, and I'm using several VPN technologies together on the same machine for similar reasons, but different methods.
As @fswings asked: why the double vpn when you could've doubled ssh, ie:

```
Phone --SSH-> AWS ==VPN--ssh->==> remoteVPN
```

The one problem you need be carefull of, especially when you aren't in control of the other VPN, is the IPs and routing. Thus, you'll find that in the end you'll have the PPTP VPN setup to the remote site, and then you'll find it easiest to double ssh, first to the AWS, and then on the AWS you'll ssh to the remote site.